# Eagles vs. drones: Are Dutch police training drone-hunting eagles?

Tags: netherlands, police, birds

In [this Vice article](https://motherboard.vice.com/read/dutch-police-train-eagles-to-tackle-drones), it is mentioned that the Dutch police are training eagles to hunt drones.

> In a new project to patrol the skies, the Dutch national police force has teamed up with ‘Guard from Above,’ a company that trains birds of prey to tackle drones. They aim to create a fleet of eagles that can take to the skies and prey on drones that infringe air space or hamper official operations such as emergency air ambulance landings. According to Guard from Above, the goal is to draw on the bird’s “hunting instincts” to make them hunt down drones.

While we do see a [video of an eagle getting a drone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HifO-ebmE1s), is it really an official training program?

Comment: Interestingly, [according to the Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2016/feb/08/scotland-yard-interested-in-using-eagles-to-take-down-drones), the British Police is considering to do the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Are Dutch police training drone-hunting eagles?

Not exactly, as the article explains, there is a start-up called "Guard from Above" who is proposing this solution, but it is not the same thing as the Dutch police. The Dutch police is their customer:

> WHO ARE YOUR CLIENTS?
>
> We work mainly for national and international governmental security agencies. One of our important clients, with whom we
>   work closely, is the Dutch National Police. Together, we are participating in an innovation project in order to research the
>   possibilities of using birds of prey against the undesirable use of drones.

None of the founders is a policeman:

> THE PEOPLE BEHIND GUARD FROM ABOVE (GFA)
>
> - Ben de Keijzer [COO]: Ben de Keijzer has been training birds of prey for more than 25 years. [...]
> - Sjoerd Hoogendoorn [CEO]: Sjoerd Hoogendoorn has experience in the security sector and has spent years studying the
>     various ways that drones are used. [...]

—[Guard from Above](http://guardfromabove.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/NL-ENG-Guard-From-Above-Press-Release-FAQ.pdf) leaflet

On the other hand, the Dutch Police also confirms in this [press release](https://www.politie.nl/nieuws/2016/januari/31/wereldprimeur-politie-zet-roofvogels-in-om-drones-uit-te-schakelen.html):

> Nederland - In een innovatief project van de Nationale Politie in samenwerking met Guard From Above, een bedrijf dat roofvogels traint, wordt gekeken naar de mogelijkheid om roofvogels in te zetten voor het onderscheppen van vijandige drones.

Translation:

> Netherlands - In an innovative project of the National Police in collaboration with Guard From Above, a company that trains raptors, the ability to use birds of prey for intercepting enemy drones is being investigated.

Comment: Here is the video in which an innovation manager from the Dutch police confirms the experiments: https://youtu.be/HifO-ebmE1s